# How fast data store query expires?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How fast data store query expires ? I googled but didn't find number in documentation.

Code throws:

```
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreFailureException: query has expired or is invalid. Please restart it with the last cursor to read more results.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's 30 seconds.

Semi-official answer was given by Google employee in their bugtracking system **[here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4432)**.

Answer (score 2):

A query cursor can last hours.  If you're getting this error consistently in a short amount of time after performing the query for the first time, it may mean your cursor string is incorrect, or you are using the cursor with an incorrect query.  (The query must be identical to the one used to generate the cursor.)

If you change the configuration of a composite index that powers a query, all existing cursors are invalidated.  [The docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Query_Cursors) suggest that a change to the underlying implementation (by the App Engine team) can also invalidate cursors.

Comment: It's consistent after 30 seconds :) I just wanted to see official information about it. But all I found (after I posted this question) is [this comment](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4432) in bugtracking system.

Comment: I think you may be talking about two different things that are both, confusingly, called cursors. Dan is referring to the cursors that can be used for paginating UIs. Those indeed have no limit on their lifetime -- they only become less accurate over time as keys get deleted or inserted. But the 30 second timeout is more likely referring to the "internal cursor" that ties consecutive batches of a single query together. If you're using Appstats this is RunQuery - Next - Next etc. That's what the comment in issue 4432 refers to. Maybe you're doing some kind of long background job?